# Is it possible to save file to desktop? Windows Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I need a way to download file to desktop.

As per my research I find way to **Save a file to an app-specific directory** i.e(LocalFolder,RoamingFolder,TemporaryFolder) ,**DownloadsFolder**  and **KnownFolders** i.e(DocumentsLibrary,PictureLibrary,MusicLibrary,VideoLibrary and RemovableDevices).

C# provide a way to get path to desktop and create file

```
var desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
var fullFileName = Path.Combine(desktopFolder, "Test.txt");
var fs = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
```

but there is no *SpecialFolder* or *GetFolderPath* exist in class *Environment*

So my question -

> Is it possible to save file to desktop with windows store app? if possible then please let me
>   know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible in direct way. You must use `FolderPicker` at least one time and request user to select `Desktop` folder. Then store that folder in [`FutureAccessList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457). Then you can store files in that folder.